# Does an AppMobi app require Applab?

Tags: android, ios, html, appmobi

Will an HTML5 app, made with AppMobi, always require applab to be installed on the users phone?  Or can I build it as a standalone app?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

appLab is used for testing the app without needing to build it using "Test Anywhere".

When you are ready, you can build your app into a binary and distribute it.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct.  The beauty of the appLab is that you can update the "test anywhere" version from the XDK, and then you can run the appLab to run the app in any of the devices you want, before having to go through the hassle of getting it to build on all those platforms.  Another great thing about it is if you just want to whip out a simple app, just to help figure out how to make some new feature work, you never have to go through all the settings for each platform, and the provisioning BS on iOS to see if it works on the iOS platforms.  The biggest downside, which isn't a big deal, is that when you switch to another app, say to read your email, when you come back you aren't where you left off in your app withing appLab, but you start over at the appLab main screen.